# cohomological criterion of triviality

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Hi,

let $X$ be a proper curve, not necessarily smooth, but reduced and connected and $E$ a vector bundle on $X$ of rank $r$.

For a line bundle $L$ it is true that the conditions $h^0(X,L)>0$ and $h^0(X,L^{\vee})>0$ are equivalent to say $L\cong\mathcal{O}$.

Is it true in general that we can find a constant $c$, depending on the rank, such that the condition $h^0(X,E)>c$ and $h^0(X,E^{\vee})>c$ are equivalent to say that $E$ is trivial?

Thanks

Comment: No, consider $E=\mathcal{O}(n)\oplus \mathcal{O}(-m)$ on 
$\mathbb{P}^1$ with $n,m\gg 0$.

Comment: @jikki: You have asked the same question on math.stackexchange two hours ago (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331228). Next time, please don't conceal this for the readers on MO.

Comment: Jikki, you're welcome. If you *really* need such a result, you should 
probably require $E$ to be semistable.

Comment: @Donu Arapura thanks for the hint. I guess we should also add degree zero. In the stable case it is clear because $h^0(X,E)\geq r$ gives me a non zero homomorphism $O^r\rightarrow E$, so that it is an isomorphism by stability. Assume $E$ is an extension $0\rightarrow F_1 \rightarrow E\rightarrow F_2\rightarrow 0$ with $F_1$ and $F_2$ stable and of rank $r_1$ and $r_2$. The fact $h^0(E)>r-1$ gives me a morphism $a: \mathcal{O}^{r_2}\rightarrow E \rightarrow F_2$ and the fact that $h^0(E^{\vee})>r-1$ gives me a morphism $b:F_1\rightarrow E\rightarrow \mathcal{O}^{r_1}$, if one can find $a,b$ non

Comment: zero then $F_1\cong \mathcal{O}^{r_1}$ and $F_2\cong \mathcal{O}^{r_2}$. Since $\mathcal{O}^r\rightarrow \mathcal{O}^{r_2}$ splits by composing with $\mathcal{O}^r\rightarrow E$ we get a splitting of the extension which implies $E\cong F_1\oplus F_2\cong\mathcal{O}^r$. For bigger extension it is analogous. The problem is to show $a,b\neq 0$....any idea?

Comment: Dear @Donu, it seems that the huge numbers $n=m=1$ are sufficient to ensure $n,m\gt\gt 1$ :-)  

Comment: @Georges: Donu may have meant to say $>0$.... :)

Comment: Georges, yes you're right, $1\gg 0$ in this case!

Comment: If $X$ is reducible, the statement fails also for line bundles. Take $X=C_1\cup C_2$ to be the union of two rational curves meeting in a point and $L$ a line bundle of degree $n$ on $C_1$ and $-n$ on $C_2$.